# Laravel Eloquent ORM query not working Laravel v6.9

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I can't query my model in my controller.

```php
$model = MyModel::find(1)->get();
```

but it says:

> Method 'find' not found in \App\MyModel

Laravel version 6.9

Comment: Can you show the content of your model?

Comment: Also when you use `find`, you do not need `get`. The `find` method returns automatically the first model of the collection.

Comment: did  `MyModel extends Model`?

Comment: @TsaiKoga yes,,

Comment: class MyModel extends Model { /** * The table associated with the model. * * @var string */ // Tell the model which table it is to use protected $table = 'my_model'; protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // Mass-assignment protection prevents fields // from being filled by default. Tell the model which // fields are fillable. protected $fillable = [ 'name', ]; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like `$model = MyModel::find(1);` or `$model = MyModel::where('id', 1)->first();` and don't forget to extend Model class in your MyModel class like `MyModel extends Model{}` . It will work try and see.

Comment: It's the same "Method 'find' not found in \App\MyModel"

Comment: can you give the ```MyModel``` class code? I want full code.

Comment: did you import this ```use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;``` in your above model?

Comment: <code>class MyModel extends Model
    {  /**  
     * The table associated with the model.  
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // Tell the model which table it is to use
    protected $table = 'my_model';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Mass-assignment protection prevents fields
    // from being filled by default. Tell the model which
    // fields are fillable.
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];
}</code>

Comment: Yes,
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

Comment: try ```$models = MyModel::all();``` and see working or not

Comment: yes, it works. My other question if I use all() how can I use push the update:


$model = MyModel::all();
$model->name = 'Sen';
$model->push();

Comment: for which element you want to update you find that element and update it. For example in the array 4th element (index - 3). 
```$models = MyModel::all();``` 
```$models[3]->name = 'Sen';```
It will update no need to push.

Comment: for your find problem see my answer. I edited. You can use ```$model = MyModel::where('id', 1)->first();``` It will work same as find.

Comment: No error, it was successful , but the table in my local database didn't change.

Comment: if you add like this ```$models = MyModel::all();```  ```$models[3]->name = 'Sen';``` ```$models[3]->save();``` then it will store in database as well. Check my answer for your find error it will solve your problem. It solve give thumps up and approval for the answer.